# Can't start my virtual Box machine after installing Docker on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox, archlinux

To learn ArchLinux, I installed and using ArchLinux in a VirtualBox machine. It runs perfectly. Now I installed Docker on my pc (Windows environment). During the installation of Docker I got a warning, that if I install Docker on Windows, that VirtualBox cant boot my machine's anymore cause of ...

I uninstalled Docker and hoped that I could still use my ArchLinux. But I cant!

Do anyone know what to do, to run VirtualBox and the machines inside correctly again?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

VirtualBox can't run anymore because Docker for Windows activates Hyper-V during its installation (with your permission). So you have to disable this feature again. You have to uncheck `Hyper-V` in `Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off`. After a reboot, VirtualBox should be able to run again.

Comment: thank you thats solved it!
I knew it was something with hyper-v but i couldnt remember what.

Comment: Saved my day... I thought I need to turn on the Hyper-V according to the vbox error msg.

Comment: I also needed to disable Hypervisor like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50053255/virtualbox-raw-mode-is-unavailable-courtesy-of-hyper-v-windows-10

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem.

I just due to changing Hyper-V Launch Type using BCDEDIT.

You can try setting the launch type to Off by running the command below:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Please see this post => [How to Disable Hyper-V Completely in Windows 10](https://www.petri.com/how-to-disable-hyper-v-completely-in-windows-10)

Comment: This command fixed it for me. But open Powershell with admin rights and then run the command.

Comment: To turn it on again use `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto` on a terminal with root access and reboot.

Comment: You also need to restart your PC so changes take effect

Answer (score 6):

i have the same problem. but after turn off hyper-V,i still can't open my virtual machine. 
then i upgrade virtualbox to the latest version,then virtual box works again.

Comment: I could not start my virtual machines after turning off Hyper-V Windows feature as well. I had to repair my VirtualBox installation using the VirtualBox Setup.

Comment: same to me, i updated from version 6.0.4 to 6.1.14 and my virtual machine starts again

Answer (score 3):

You have to uncheck Hyper-V and Virtual Machine Platform (if checked)  in Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off. After a reboot, VirtualBox should be able to run again.

Comment: This is similar to the most popular answer but adds "Virtual Machine Platform" which is what mattered for me

Answer (score 1):

Now VirtualBox and Hyper-V can work together!

https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/use-virtualbox-and-hyper-v-together-on-windows-10.html